# 'this' keyword doesn’t always refer to the object on which a method is defined, but instead can change based on specific contexts. How?

Tags: javascript, this

I was going through this article http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/objects-in-javascript/ 
where I read "'this' keyword doesn’t always refer to the object on which a method is defined, but instead can change based on specific contexts." 
I couldn't find any example in which 'this' does not refer to the object on a method is defined....please gimme an example if possible

Comment: this [link](http://www.digital-web.com/articles/scope_in_javascript/) was kinda helpful but not that good...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many way to change context. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wAcYD/)

using bind: (not supported by older IE browsers (IE < 9))

```
    var obj = {}; 
    function fun1(){};
    obj2 = {};
    obj2.fun1 =  fun1.bind(obj);
    obj2.fun1(); // context inside fun1 would be obj.
```

Using apply or call.

```
var obj = {}; 
        function fun1(){};
        obj2 = {};
        obj2.fun1 =  function(){
            fun1.apply(obj, arguments);
            //or fun1.call(obj, ar1, arg2,...);
          };
        obj2.fun1(); // context inside fun1 would be obj.
```

Answer (score 3):

One example that you could realistically run into and not expect this result:

```
var obj = {
    testFunc : function(){
        alert("testFunc: " + this);
    }
}

obj.testFunc();  // this is the object

setTimeout(obj.testFunc, 1000);  // this is window
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t7ycd/

Comment: why did it refer to window the next time ?

Comment: Because he passed reference of function and settimeout always call it with context as window.

Answer (score 1):

Here is *one* way

```
var a = {};
a.foo = function(){ console.log(this); }
a.foo(); // object a
a.foo.call(window); // window object
```

Answer (score 0):

If you call a method in class B from class A, the 'this' will refer to the class that is calling the method - A, not the class that it is in.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example taken directly from the Mozilla documentation

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

```
var o = {prop: 37};

function independent() {
  return this.prop;
}

o.f = independent;

console.log(o.f()); // logs 37
```

So the function `independent` is defined in the global context, but is then attached to an object. When it is invoked on that object the context becomes the object on which the function is invoked rather than the object on which the function is defined.

You can achieve similar results using the javascript `call` and `bind` methods, and using anonymous functions.

Answer (score 0):

like this

```
var MyObject = function()
{
 this.initialize();
}

MyObject.prototype.SomeMethod = function()
{
 //common fix is to use
 //var self = this;
 (function(){
    //this has lost scope
    //self will retain the this scope that was desired
 })();
}
```